# How to Create a Backup Server in TCP Java Application,

Tags: java, tcp, client-server

I have a Java application that has a TCP Server and It handles the client requests. Now I want to create a TCP backup Server, so that when the TCP Server Fails, the backup server continues from the point the TCP Server failed and Handle the client request.

How this can be done?

I have a client and a server.

This is my code for TCP Server for now..

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import javax.script.ScriptEngineManager;
import javax.script.ScriptEngine;
import javax.script.ScriptException;

public class TCPServer {
        static ScriptEngineManager mgr;
        static ScriptEngine engine;
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        mgr = new ScriptEngineManager();
        engine = mgr.getEngineByName("js");
        try {
            int serverPort = 7896; // the server port
            ServerSocket listenSocket = new ServerSocket(serverPort);

            while (true) {
                System.out.println("Server is ready and waiting for requests .... ");
                Socket clientSocket = listenSocket.accept();
                System.out.println("request received from client with IP : " + clientSocket.getInetAddress());
                System.out.println("port of client : " + clientSocket.getPort());
                Thread c = new Connection(clientSocket);

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            //if already in use then redirect the request to backup server
            System.out.println("Listen socket:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}

class Connection extends Thread {

    DataInputStream in;
    DataOutputStream out;
    Socket clientSocket;

    public Connection(Socket aClientSocket) {
        try {
            clientSocket = aClientSocket;
            in = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
            out = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
            this.start();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Connection:" + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

    public void run() { 

        //send client request to bacckup server, with client IP adddress and port number
        //BackupTCPServer bus = new BackupTCPServer();
        //bus.clientIP = clientSocket.getInetAddress();
        //bus.clientPort = clientSocket.getPort();
        //System.out.println(bus);
        try {


            String s = in.readUTF();
            //bus.Expressionsbackup.add(s);
            String exp = "";
            int res = 0;
            while (s != null) {
                TCPServer.engine.put("i", 2);
                TCPServer.engine.put("j", 4);
                exp =s;
                Object result = TCPServer.engine.eval(exp);
                double st = (Double)result;
                out.writeUTF(Double.toString(st));
                //bus.expressionevaluated++;

                s = in.readUTF();
            }




        }
        catch (ScriptException se) {
            System.out.println("SE:" + se.getMessage());
        } 
        catch (EOFException e) {
            System.out.println("EOF:" + e.getMessage());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("readline:" + e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            try {
                clientSocket.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                /*close failed*/
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your application deploy in the same JVM or different JVM？

Comment: Same JVM @TongChen

Comment: in the same JVM is no need to create a backup server.